# StackOverflow Exception + Source information is missing from the debug information for this module

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have problem with Visual Studio 2015 and .NET Framework 4.5.2. In my ASP.NET MVC project I changed something CSS and then when wanted to debug I got:

> 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Also message:

> Source not available.   Source information is missing from the debug
>   information for this module

I'm not sure, but before this message was other message about Symbols (I have clicked something and then got this message "Source not available..".

Call stack:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(System.RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, System.Type type) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.GetDataContract(System.RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, System.Type type) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.GetDataContract(System.RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, System.Type type)    Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson.SerializeWithXsiType(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, System.RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, System.Type objectType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, System.Type declaredType) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplex.InternalSerialize(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, object obj, bool isDeclaredType, bool writeXsiType, int declaredTypeID, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)  Unknown
>       System.Runtime.Serialization.dll!System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.JsonCollectionDataContract.WriteJsonValueCore(System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlWriterDelegator jsonWriter, object obj, System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContextComplexJson context, System.RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle) Unknown

Comment: I believe its due to loop reference in your object being serialized

Comment: i dont serialize anything

Comment: try to turn on break on all exceptions and find out which line is throwing that. without further information we cant help much

Answer (score 0):

I had to Disable Browser Link using Visual Studio settings not web.config.